# Lucas Kanade: How to calculate distance between tracked points

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, computer-science

I'm using lucas-kanade opencv implementation to track objects between frames. I want to be able to do the following two things:

- Calculate the distance moved by ***each point*** between frames
- Track bounding boxes for each object across frames

I have obtained the features to track using `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack()`. I also add the bounding boxes of objects to the features to be tracked. Right now I am using the following to calculate distance between the points
`np.sqrt(np.square(new_pts - old_pts).sum(axis=1).sum(axis=1))`. I am not quite sure if this is the correct way to do this because the indices of the points might be different in the new_pts. 
Is the assumption that every index in old_pts corresponds to  the same feature in new_pts array correct?

Secondly, is there a way to track bounding boxes across frames using lucas kanade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In new_pts points have the same index. But they can be not founded - see to the status array: if status[i] == 1 then new_pts[i] contains a new coordinates of the old_pts[i].

For the more robustness it can to search direct flow (goodFeaturesToTrack(frame1) -> LK flow), backward flow (goodFeaturesToTrack(frame2) -> LK flow) and leave the points whose coordinates are equal in both directions.

Comment: Great! Thank you!